# What is the reason for this error----ValueError: too many values to unpack?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, valueerror

I'm working on an image classification problem. My dataset can be find [here](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/nnytj2v3n5/1).

In the following code `main_data_dir` is a path to a folder which contains 40 individual forders with name of the leaf each containing more than 50 number of images of leaf.

The output should identify the name of the leaf from the leaf image.

I get this error when I run the code to load my dataset `ValueError: too many values to unpack?`

```
%%time

(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = os.listdir(main_data_dir)

trainX = 1 - (trainX / 255.0)
testX  = 1 - (testX / 255.0)

trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX, axis=-1)
testX = np.expand_dims(testX, axis=-1)

(pairTrain, labelTrain) = make_pairs(trainX, trainY)
(pairTest, labelTest) = make_pairs(testX, testY)

print(f'\nTrain Data Shape: {pairTrain.shape}')
print(f'Test  Data Shape: {pairTest.shape}\n\n')
```

I don't know why? Could you help me solving this problem?

Comment: After `(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = os.listdir(main_data_dir)` can you please print `(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY)` and also the shape

Comment: Nothing is getting printed ,the same error shows up again

Comment: How to split a folder of leaf image dataset,whose path is in the string "main_data_dir"

Comment: `os.listdir` return the list of files and folders contained in `main_data_dir`. It doesn't split you dataset. So you should explain us your dataset format

Comment: main_data_dir is a path to a folder which contains 40 individual forders with name of the leaf each containing more than 50 number of images of leaf.

Comment: And the final task is to predict the type of leaf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255314/discussion-between-marco-parola-and-jeeva-joslin).

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your dataset, I unzipped it so in the root project I have my python file and a folder containing your dataset; this is the path `Medicinal Leaf Dataset/Segmented Medicinal Leaf Images`.

The following code contains a function that correctly loads both images and labels as numpy array.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def load_leaf_dataset(main_data_dir):
    image_arrays = []
    labels = []
    print("Loading images...")

    for folder_name in os.listdir(main_data_dir):
        print(f"Loading images from {folder_name}...")
        folder_path = os.path.join(main_data_dir, folder_name)
        if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
            label = folder_name.split(" ")[-1][1:-1]  # Extract abbreviation from folder name
            for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
                print(f"\tLoading {filename}...")
                if filename.endswith(".jpg"):  # Assuming the images are in JPG format
                    image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                    try:
                        image = Image.open(image_path)
                        image_array = np.array(image)
                        image_arrays.append(image_array)
                        labels.append(label)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error loading {image_path}: {str(e)}")

    # Convert lists to numpy arrays
    image_arrays = np.array(image_arrays)
    labels = np.array(labels)

    return image_arrays, labels


# Example usage:
main_data_dir = "./Medicinal Leaf Dataset/Segmented Medicinal Leaf Images"
image_arrays, labels = load_leaf_dataset(main_data_dir)
```

The next steps to be taken are:

- convert your labels in categorical ones.
- split the dataset in trai, val and test sets (I suggest sklearn)
- Declare and train your classifier